# Javascript: Convert number to string with 'excel-like formatting'

Tags: javascript

I'd like to copy this formula (From Google sheets actually), in Javascript:

```
=TEXT(9,"0000000")
```

This would result in '0000009'

Is this possible in a single function without additional logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function like this could look like:

```
function TEXT(n, format){
 return format.substring(0,format.length - n.toString().length) + n;
}
```

Comment: return format.substring(0,format.length - n.toString().length - 1) + n;

Answer (score 1):

You could also use recursion where `pad` is the length of the final string required.

```
function text(str, pad) {
  return pad > 1 ? '0' + text(str, --pad) : str;
}

text(9, 8); // 00000009
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/o0bz03mk/)

Slightly optimised version:

```
function text(str, n, padder) {
  if (n === 1) return str;
  return text(padder + str, --n, padder);
}

text(9, 8, '0');
```

Comment: What would be the benefit of this over the perfectly working solution above?? - other than being cooler

Comment: None really. It could be better by passing in the padding string too. I've just been getting into recursion a bit recently :) This probably needs to be refactored a little because of the lack of tail-optimisation in JS, but then it wouldn't be a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this lib
https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel-style-dataformatter

So for your case:
`result = dataFormatter.format(9, "Number", "0000000")`

Comment: That does look helpful